# Mysql query not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

```
CREATE DATABASE `menu`;

USE menu;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fish`;

SET @saved_cs_client = @@character_set_client;

SET character_set_client = utf8;

CREATE TABLE `fish` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`NAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL default ‘’,
`PRICE` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL default ‘0.00’,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
LOCK TABLES `fish` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `fish` VALUES 
(1,’catfish’,’8.50’),(2,’catfish’,’8.50’),(3,’tuna’,’8.00’),
(4,’catfish’,’5.00’),(5,’bass’,’6.75’),(6,’haddock’,’6.50’),
(7,’salmon’,’9.50’),(8,’trout’,’6.00’),(9,’tuna’,’7.50’),
(10,’yellowfin tuna’,’12.00’),(11,’yellowfin tuna’,’13.00’),(12,’tuna’,’7.50’);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I'm currently reading this book on how to use MySQL with python and would like to know why this query from the book is not currently working.( **MySQL version 5.6 and workbench 6.2 in Windows 7**)

**Things I have tried**

1. Typing in the code by hand
2. Copying and pasting from the pdf into notepad++, workbench and notepad
3. I copied the file into notepad and saved it in different encoding such as UTF-9

It is probably something simple I am missing, but I am new to this.

The error message get when running the query.

> 11:25:50  CREATE TABLE `fish` ( `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, `NAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL default ‘’, `PRICE` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL default ‘0.00’, PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
>
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘’, `PRICE` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL default ‘0.00’, PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ) E' at line 3  0.000 sec

Comment: You say it's not working, but you don't include an error message in your question? I imagine it is due to lots of different quotation marks being used

Comment: Hello @Phil I edited the query and added the error message.

Comment: You've got multiple different quotation marks, as I said. Replace them all with '

Comment: String constants need to be enclosed with `'` (straight single quotes), not with `’` (some "curly" single quote)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the quotes you are using for the default of `NAME`.

Here is your original create table from the question

```
CREATE TABLE `fish` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`NAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL default ‘’, <<--- LOOK HERE
`PRICE` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL default ‘0.00’,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

You gave `default ‘’` and the mysql client does not understand it.

You need to express it with standard single quotes like this : `default ''`

I just noticed that [a_horse_with_no_name's comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89395/mysql-query-not-working#comment160080_89395) already says this.

Don't change anything else. Leave all other quotes as is.

**Give it a Try !!!**

Comment: It worked after trying your code.  The quotes where were I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'menu';

    USE menu;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'fish';

    SET @saved_cs_client = @@character_set_client;

    SET character_set_client = utf8;

    CREATE TABLE 'fish' (
    'ID' int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    'NAME' varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
    'PRICE' decimal(5,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY ('ID')
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
    SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
    LOCK TABLES 'fish' WRITE;

    INSERT INTO 'fish' VALUES 
    (1,'catfish','8.50'),(2,'catfish','8.50'),(3,'tuna','8.00'),
    (4,'catfish','5.00'),(5,'bass','6.75'),(6,'haddock','6.50'),
    (7,'salmon','9.50'),(8,'trout','6.00'),(9,'tuna','7.50'),
    (10,'yellowfin tuna','12.00'),(11,'yellowfin tuna','13.00'),(12,'tuna','7.50');

    UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Use ' to string my friends.